Нужно удалять все указатели или нет?
Если я создал пирамиду указателей на переменную и при закрытии приложения я удалил переменную, нужно ли мне удалить все ненужные указатели?
Пример:
SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

SDL_Texture** pTexture = &texture;

SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);

Что будет с указателем?

Любой delete должен быть парным к соответствующему new. В вашем случае память не была выделена (new), её не надо удалять (delete).

На один вызов new - один вызов delete. Если нет new, то delete не нужон.

Здесь нельзя удалять ни один указатель. Будут неприятности...

А если удалю основу указатели будут зассорять память или нет?

а как вы удалите статическую переменную?

Понял что сделал не тот пример, сейчас переделаю

С указателем ничего не будет, он будет продолжать указывать на адрес переменной texture. Освобождать, как уже сказали - не нужно.

Спасибо большое

То же самое, на один вызов Create... - один вызов Destroy.... Указатели сами по себе больше никакого "удаления" не требуют.
